# using javascript function in php while loop

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to multiply values in two text boxes and place it on a third text box... Using javascript and php while loop with onclick event.....How to do that??
my code is

```
<script language="javascript">

    function multiply()
    {

       var textValue1 = document.getElementById('CLS').value;
       var textValue2 = document.getElementById('rate').value;

       document.getElementById('valuation').value = textValue1 * textValue2;

    }
    </script>
<?php
$a="some query";
$b=mysql_query($a);
while($c=mysql_fetch_array($b))

{
echo "<td>".$CLOSINGstk."</td>
<input type='hidden' name='CLOSINGstk".$a."' value='".$CLOSINGstk."' id='CLS".$a."'>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='rate".$a."' id='rate".$a."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='valuation".$a."' id='valuation".$a."' onclick='multiply();'></td>";
}
?>
```

Comment: [`mysql_*` api id deprecated so either use pdo or mysqli and imo use pdo](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: Just to clarify before I answer, you want this to happen instantly in the input boxes and not process through PHP and reload the page, correct?

Comment: why are you printing query in html ?

Comment: Please name those easier than $a, $b, $c , $d, $e......$z. It is tough for others to read and understand this code that way: hence the mistakes in all of the answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">

    function multiply(arg_id)
    {

       var textValue1 = document.getElementById('CLS'+arg_id).value;
       var textValue2 = document.getElementById('rate'+arg_id).value;

       document.getElementById('valuation'+arg_id).value = textValue1 * textValue2;

    }
    </script>
<?php
$a="some query";
$b=mysql_query($a);
while($c=mysql_fetch_array($b))

{
echo "<td>".$CLOSINGstk."</td>
<input type='hidden' name='CLOSINGstk".$a."' value='".$CLOSINGstk."' id='CLS".$a."'>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='rate".$a."' id='rate".$a."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='valuation".$a."' id='valuation".$a."' onclick='multiply(".$a.");'></td>";
}

?>
```

just pass parameter as id from all `CLS,RATE,VALUATION`

let me know i can help you more.

Comment: Sorry but did you read their code really before answering? their `$a` is a MySQL query which means you, just like them, are storing a MySQL query as `name` and `id` of fields.

Comment: i am agree but he just need to change variable which content CLS and Rate. here i have given logic to implement and solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
while($c=mysql_fetch_array($b)) {
echo "<td>
          <input type='text' name='valuation".$c['id']."'
           id='valuation".$c['id']."' onkeypress='multiply(".$c['id'].");'>  //Let you want to pass id from DB
      </td>";
```

or you can use

```
onkeypress='multiply('.$c['id'].')'
```

USE **onkeypress** instead of **onclick**() and in your script

```
function multiply(id)
{

   var textValue1 = document.getElementById('CLS'+id).value;
   var textValue2 = document.getElementById('rate'+id).value;

   document.getElementById('valuation'+id).value = textValue1 * textValue2;

}
```

And try to avoid mysql_* functions because they are depricated,instead use either **mysqli_*** functions or **PDO** statements

Comment: Sorry but did you read their code really before answering? their `$a` is a MySQL query which means you, just like them, are storing a MySQL query as `name` and `id` of fields.

Comment: am not passing the id from my database ..... This is an input just given manually.......

Comment: And consider the script also...you done lot of mistakes in your script also

Comment: Thanks@Mr.Gautam3164... But i think there is no use of onkeypress event......The CLS value is default and we are gonna to enter the rate and it must be displays on valuation........

Comment: @Pilaventhiran for the text box what is the need to put onclick event...it is not good

Comment: @Gautam3164..ya ..... but am just trying from the basic .... if there is any replacement ... please tell me that too

Comment: But @Pilaventhiran it is also a basic that ..for an text box onkeypress,onblur,...like events will be used

Comment: oh yes ... thanks @Gautam3164..... code is working .... and i wanna to know that ... without touching that third text(valuation) box how to show the values