# Automatically combine values of two text boxes in Javascript to display in a third

Tags: php, javascript

am having PHP code and javascript to multiply two values .... Here my problem is that ... if i click on the third box or button then only it shows the result .... I want the result on the third box without clicking it .... Help me

```
<script language="javascript">
    function multiply(arg_id)
    {
        var textValue1 = document.getElementById('CLS'+arg_id).value;
        var textValue2 = document.getElementById('rate'+arg_id).value;
        document.getElementById('valuation'+arg_id).value = textValue1 * textValue2;
    }
</script>
<?php
    $a="some query";
    $b=mysql_query($a);
    while($c=mysql_fetch_array($b))
    {
        echo "<td>".$CLOSINGstk."</td><input type='hidden' name='CLOSINGstk".$a."' value='".$CLOSINGstk."' id='CLS".$a."'>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='rate".$a."' id='rate".$a."'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='button' name='valuation".$a."' id='valuation".$a."' onclick='multiply(".$a.");'></td>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your same question posted a few hours earlier? Web space is becoming costlier by the day. You accepted an answer too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932373/using-javascript-function-in-php-while-loop/

Comment: You should use jQuery everything is alot easier there.

Comment: You can use `onblur` method.

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ ya but at the same time i wanna to fill that text box automatically .... there is no code for that in that link ... think so...

Comment: You don't even need javascript for it, Fill everything in PHP and send away

Comment: when you want the result at the time of page load or after document load and on any event on page?

Comment: Yeah, use jQuery. All your base are belong to us!! It will even make your coffee taste better.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is your code setting the SQL query as the name and ID for your input tags? The reason I say this is that if there is more than one item returned with the query, you are giving multiple elements the same ID which is not valid HTML.

Comment: You could try to do this in PHP for once. And the php script that you posted it,s not quite good, as I know. You are echo-ing $a, which is "some query" and not the element fetched from the array, $c.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

**IN PHP CODE:**

```
while($c=mysql_fetch_array($b))
{
echo "<td>".$CLOSINGstk."</td><input type='hidden' name='CLOSINGstk".$a."' value='".$CLOSINGstk."' id='CLS".$a."'>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='rate".$a."' id='rate".$a."' onblur='multiply(".$a.");'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='button' name='valuation".$a."' id='valuation".$a."'></td>";
}
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Do some changes in PHP CODE:

```
while($c=mysql_fetch_array($b))
{
    echo "<td>".$CLOSINGstk."</td><input type='hidden' name='CLOSINGstk".$a."' value='".$CLOSINGstk."' id='CLS".$a."'>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='rate".$a."' id='rate".$a."' onblur='multiply(".$a.");'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='button' name='valuation".$a."' id='valuation".$a."'></td>";
}
```

It will help I hope..