# Calculate values in two input boxes and get result in third input box using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

```
<table><tr> 
        <?php
        if ($_POST['class']) {
            $sql6 = mysql_query("select * from sr_reg where present_class='$_POST[class]' order by id ASC");
            $num6 = mysql_num_rows($sql6);
            if ($num6) {
                $i = 0;
                while ($val6 = mysql_fetch_array($sql6)) {
                    $i = $i + 1;
                    ?>

                <form name="frm1" action="class.php" method="post">
                    <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <div align="center"><strong>
                                <?php echo $i ?><input type="hidden" name="class" value="<?php echo $_POST['class']; ?>" />
                            </strong></div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FCD5B4">
                        <div align="center">
                            <input type="text" name="roll" value=""  />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#C5BE97">
                        <div align="center">
                            <?php echo $val6['studentname'] . " " . $val6['sname']; ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#D99795">
                        <input type="text" name="oral"   id="txt_oral[]"  onkeyup="totalMarks();"/>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#8DB4E3">
                        <div align="center">
                            <input type="text" name="writen" id="txt_writen[]" onkeyup="totalMarks();" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#D7E4BC" colspan="2">
                        <div align="center">
                            <input type="text" name="tot"  id="txt_tot[]" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    } else {

    }
} else {

}
?>
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do? You should clarify your question and provide some background context.

Comment: I need the calculation of input id ="txt_oral" and "txt_writen" and the total should be come in id ="txt_tot"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my answer in thread[liyakat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16932481/2092477)

I just changed the value * to + and added parseInt to make input values in number. function multiply changed in calculation
and onkeyup='calculate(".$i.");' in first user input and second user input .
answer is working in id='txt_tot".$i."'
its working well!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery:

```
$("#txt_tot").val($("#txt_oral").val() + $("#txt_written.val());
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

If you don't want to use jQuery for this project

```
document.getElementById('txt_tot').value = document.getElementById('txt_oral').value + document.getElementById('txt_written').value;
```

Comment: its not a single row I fetched student name from class they may be in any number . so I put id="txt_oral[]",and so on I need array function in javascript which I can't understand. I need like this: var i=0;
for(i=0; i<count(document.getElementById); i++){

    function calculate () {
// The Calculation: change operator in this equation to change the   calculation
     txt_tot = txt_oral + txt_writen;
    }